# Where to put the unreal engine python library for pylint

Tags: python, windows, unreal-engine4

I'm playing around with the Unreal Engine 4 and the [python plugin](https://github.com/20tab/UnrealEnginePython). Adding it and getting it to work is no problem (win64, python 3.6.5 64bit) but since almost every py file for unreal starts out with `import unreal_engine` and I don't have that installed to the system like I would with something from `pip install` I'm wondering where to put what part of that repo so I don't have the pylint error `[pylint] E0401:Unable to import 'unreal_engine'` and lots of other "errors" like the following:

```
class Hero:
    # this is called on game start
    def begin_play(self):
        self.startZ = self.uobject.get_actor_location().z
```

the last line with `self.` presents a linter error of `[pylint] E1101:Instance of 'Hero' has no 'uobject' member`.

Again I want to stress that all the code works inside of Unreal but it would be really nice to have the IDE pick the classes up right so I also get the autocomplete suggestions for available methods on `uobject.something`.

I'm fairly new to python programming and only ever had to import system libraries or things installed via pip so this is confusing to me.

For reference I have installed python via the official python installer for Windows to `c:\dev\Python\Python36`. The bin folder is in windows `PATH` and all that fun stuff.